# Python Multiprocessing does not run concurrent when calling Class.Method() in Multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

I am somewhat new to python and testing how multiprocessing works in python.  I noticed that when I called a multiprocessing.process on a class object I get concurrent results (the receiver prints data before the sender is finished processing). However, when I call a multiprocessing.process on the class.method(), the receiver waits for the sender to finish before printing the items.  I am using a pipe() in this example.

I have two questions.

1. why does the `Class.Method()` call not run concurrently?
2. why does the Class / Function call work correctly?  What is the difference?

`Class.Method()` code:

```
class inherit_1:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class inherit_2:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

class sender(inherit_1, inherit_2):
    def __init__(self, a, b, conn2): 
        inherit_1.__init__(self, a)
        inherit_2.__init__(self, b) 
        self.conn2 = conn2
          
    # generate work
    def worker(self):    
        print('Sender: Running', flush=True)
        for i in range(10):
            # generate a value
            value = i*self.a + i*self.b
            sleep(1)
            self.conn2.send(value) 
        # all done
        self.conn2.send(None)
        print('Sender: Done', flush=True)

class receiver:
    def __init__(self, conn1):
        self.conn1 = conn1
        print('Receiver: Running', flush=True)
        while True:
            # get a unit of work
            item = conn1.recv() 
            print(f'>receiver got {item}', flush=True)
            # check for stop
            if item is None:
                break
        # all done
        print('Receiver: Done', flush=True)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    
    # create the pipe
    conn1, conn2 = Pipe()

    # Create an Instance of the class
    app = sender(1,2,conn2)  

    # start the sender
    sender_process = Process(target=app.worker(), args=()) 
    sender_process.start()

    # start the receiver
    receiver_process = Process(target=receiver, args=(conn1,))
    receiver_process.start()

    sender_process.join()
    receiver_process.join()
```

Class / Function Example:

```
class sender(inherit_1, inherit_2):
    def __init__(self, a, b, conn2): 
        self.conn2 = conn2
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        # generate work  
        print('Sender: Running', flush=True)
        for i in range(10):
            # generate a value
            value = i*self.a + i*self.b
            # block
            sleep(1)
            # send data
            conn2.send(value)
        # all done
        conn2.send(None)
        print('Sender: Done', flush=True) 

class receiver: 
    def __init__(self, conn1):
        self.conn1 = conn1
        print('Receiver: Running', flush=True)
        while True:
            # get a unit of work
            item = conn1.recv() 
            # report
            print(f'>receiver got {item}', flush=True)
            # check for stop
            if item is None:
                break
        # all done
        print('Receiver: Done', flush=True)

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    # create the pipe
    conn1, conn2 = Pipe()

    # start the sender - this should start an new instance
    sender_process = Process(target=sender, args=(1,2,conn2,))
    sender_process.start()

    # start the receiver
    receiver_process = Process(target=receiver, args=(conn1,)) 
    receiver_process.start()

    sender_process.join()
    receiver_process.join()
```

I tried to change the sleep value in case there was a lag between when the sender starts and receiver starts but this did not change the results.

Comment: `target=app.worker()` should be `target=app.worker`. You're calling the method immediately, not in the process.

Comment: Just like you don't put `()` in `target=sender` in the function version.